# simple question about the level set of a function of $H^{1}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider a smooth ,convex and bounded  domain $K \subset \{ x_1 = 0 \} \subset R^n$ . consider  a smooth open set  $\Omega \subset R^{n}_+ = \{ x = (x_1,..,x_n)\in R^n ; x_1 > 0\} $ with $K \subset \partial \Omega$.

Consider $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ the weak solution for the problem

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{11}
\Delta u &=& 0  \ \mbox{i}n \  \Omega  \\
u &=& 1 \ \mbox{i}n \  K \ \\
u &=& 0 \  \mbox{o}n  \ \partial \Omega\setminus K  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where the boundary conditions is in the trace sense. By the maximum principle i know that $0 \leq u \leq 1$.

Fix $0 < l < 1$. The set $\{ x \in \Omega ; u(x) = l\}$ is always non empty ? Drawing a picture its easy to see this. but i dont know how to prove this. someone can give me a help to prove or disprove this ?
by regularity theory  $u$ is continuous.maybe this helps..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that the set is always non empty and the proof is simple: it is just an application of the intermediate value theorem. Indeed, if $u$ is continuous, then it attains the boundary condition pointwise. Is there some pitfall that I am not seeing?

Comment: the maximum principle gives me $0 \leq u \leq 1$ , but i dont know if the function attains the value zero and 1 ...  it can occurs $ 1/4 \leq u \leq 1/2$ ...

Comment: I think that $u$ attains both values because it is continuous. If a continuous functions satisfies some condition in trace sense, then it satisfies the same condition pointwise.

Comment: but in my case we dont know if the function is continuous up to the boundary ...

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am being careless. But this suggests a plan. If we mollify the initial condition $\chi_K$, which we can do easily since $K$ is flat, we obtain a smooth solution which satisfies anything we want. What happens when the smoothed initial condition tends to $\chi_K$? If the solution converges uniformly then we are done. (I hope it's clear what I mean).

Comment: Good idea... But unfortunately i have no idea to how to do that ... =\

Comment: Is there any further regularity assumptions on $\partial\Omega\setminus K$?

Comment: @Tomas I forget to say this : $\Omega$ is smooth . sorry

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) book page 303 (Estimates near the boundary). First, fix a point $p\in \partial\Omega\setminus\overline{K}$. Let $\theta_i,U_i$ be as in the book, consider the function $v=\theta_i u$ and assume without loss of generality that $\partial K$ is not contained in $\overline{U_i}$.

As the trace of $u$ near $p$ is zero, you have that $v\in H_0^1(\Omega\cap U_i)$. Now you can follow Brezis proof to conclude that $v\in H^m(\Omega)$ for all $m$, which implies that $u$ is continuous near the point $p$, hence, $u(x)=0$ in a neighbourhood of $p$ in $\partial\Omega$.

Now let $q\in K$. In the same way as before, assume that $\partial K$ is not contained in $\overline{U_i}$. The trace of the function $u-1$ is zero near $q$, hence, you can consider the function $\theta_i(u-1)$ and apply the same argument as before to conclude that $u-1$ is continuous near the point $q$, therefore, $u(x)=1$ in na neighbourhood of $q$ in $\partial \Omega$.

Once $u\in C(\Omega)$ we conclude that your set is not empty.

Comment: In your second paragraph i dont understand your affirmation : by the continuity of $u$ near $p$ , $u = 0$ in a neighbourhood of $p$

Comment: @LeandroTavares, the trace of $u$ near $pq$ is equal to zero, hence, as $u$ is continuous near $p$ we conclude that $u=0$ in a neighbourhood of $p$ (a neighbourhood in the boundary!)

Comment: Tomás,a priori my function $u$ is not defined pointwise in the boundary ( only in the trace sense ) . did you mean $u=0$ in points of $int(\Omega)$ near the point p ?

Comment: Leandro, do you know the definition of trace and it's properties?